# How to configure a portlet in CQ5 by war file 

Tags: portlet, war, portal, aem

I am trying to configure to use CQ as a portal. I am referring to the link for Using CQ as a Portal :     http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-3/administering/cq_as_portal.html

I have followed all these steps

1. Configure the portlet component in CQ WCM
2. Deploy the portlet.
3. Configure the portlet.

But after deploying the portlet when i add portlet component to page by dragging the Portlet component from the sidekick , 
it is giving the error message as "**Configuration for portlet entity identifier is missing**" and when editing it .
It should give the portlet created i.e .war files uploaded in the portlet entity drop down list of  portlet component, but not giving any entry in the list .

Please help me with the portlet configuration if i missed some step or if there is some alternate way.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload the .war file into the CQSE admin (i.e. `http://localhost:4502/admin`) in order to make them appear in the list.

You'll also need to make sure that if you are using Eclipse Maven to make your .war file that it has the right settings in the portlet.xml file - the portlet class is wrong by default although that doesn't stop it appearing in the list.